# Saving Data when opening a show Path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i open my Group/Show Path, i would like it to Update some Data at the Moment of Pageload.
I need this to check what the User has allready has seen and what is new to him.

```
before_action :updateUserGroupMessages, only: [:show]
```

is already implemented. I don't get any Error, but my Data does't Change.

```
 def show
    @user = current_user
    @user.group_user_messages.each do |grpUsrMsg|
      if grpUsrMsg.group_id == @group.id &&      !@group.group_messages.last.nil?
        grpUsrMsg.last_message_id == @group.group_messages.last.id
        grpUsrMsg.save!
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `=` instead of `==`

```
grpUsrMsg.last_message_id = @group.group_messages.last.id
```

Comment: It happens, Dario :)

Comment: @dariobrunner Don't forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem, thank you!